# Cannot render image from classpath with java swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, embedded-resource

This is my code & if i run it it prints this out

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at com.auroraclient.launcher.AuroraLauncher.init(AuroraLauncher.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Im 100% sure the package & the file is there but java seems to be looking in the wrong place. does anyone know whats happening here?

```
public enum AuroraLauncher {

    instance;

    public JFrame frame;
    public AuroraPanel panel;

    public void init(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Aurora Launcher rel- 91021");
        frame.setBounds(320, 180, 1280, 720);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel = new AuroraPanel(frame);
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
        try {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/wat.png"))));
            label.setVisible(true);
            label.setBounds(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            frame.add(label);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /**
         * Layer top buttons
         */
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would consider using a full path to the resource (from the context of the class path), maybe something like `/resources/wat.png`.  Not using the leading `/` would mean it's a relative path from the class itself which would be `package/to/class/resources`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven (which I'm guessing my the use of the term /resources) then everything in the /resources folder usually just gets mapped to the root of your classpath.

So you could try this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("wat.png"))));
```

Comment: Im not using maven, i just have a file for all my resources and assets. thx for ur help tho

Comment: Ok @hopes32_, can you share the structure of your resources/assets ?